# Change image width by screen size

Tags: html, css

I have some images that I want to add to my web(the image width should be as the screen width). the problem is that there are a lot of screen which means that there is a different between each one to another screen size/resolution. I tried to set the image width to 100% but in some cases it works great and in some case it distort it. Someone can please tell me the solution to this problem?

Comment: To keep the aspect ratio make sure you only set the `width` and don't alter the `height`, as the `height` value must be `auto`.

Comment: I didn't talk about the height, only the width is my problem.

Comment: You did not talk about the height, but setting the `height` is what distorts your images, so look again through your code or use the Google Chrome Dev Tools to see where is the `height` set.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `img` CSS to `width: 100%; height: auto;`

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    hegiht: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ugg9fkbx/)**